# ¿Cómo podría sacar la primera letra de cada palabra, en angular por medio de un pipe personalizado?

Tags: angular

```
export class CambiarPipe implements PipeTransform {
  
transform (value: string): string {

    value = value.toUpperCase()
    let manda_palabra;
    let palabra;
    palabra = value.split(" ", 2);

    for(const word in palabra){
      manda_palabra = manda_palabra + word[0]
     
      console.log(manda_palabra)

    }
    return manda_palabra
  }
```

Comment: Podrías colocar a después de let palabra; un console.log('this.habilidad', this.habilidad), y ver si existe la propiedad "titulo"  al darte undefined, pareciera que no existe-

Comment: es que en mi clase Habilidades tengo el campo titulo, no se si en la forma en la que cree un objeto llamado habilidad de esa clase Habilidades me trae ese campo, no se si es la forma correcta

Comment: Verifica  el constructor de la clase si esté creando las propiedades, porque cuando la instancias te está trayendo un objeto vacío seguramente, podrías agregar el código de la clase.

Comment: hola lo hice con un pipe, cuando hago un console.log(palabras) me imprime esto: 
["001", "NUMBER"]
["007", "AUTOTRANS"]
["007", "OPERATING"]
 ["008", "OPERATING"]

hasta ahi lo tengo bien, pero cuando quiero sacar la primera letra de cada palabra me dice que es undefined0 undefined01, intente hacer con un bucle pero me manda undefined0, undefined01

Comment: Creo que me perdí, sería interesante que colocaras que recibe transform, para entender que dato se está manejando.

si querés extraer la primera letra de cada palabra no hay necesidad de que hagas un ciclo, podés hacer lo siguiente return palabra.substr(0,1), indicame que valor tiene value, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: si claro,en value tengo estos datos, 001 NUMBER 1 PLUS A PLUS AAVON ASPE,
007 AUTOTRANS LLC,
007 OPERATING LLC AGENTE 2,
008 OPERATING LLC AGENTE 3

Comment: Entiendo te viene como un array, siendo así podrías hacer lo siguiente: const word = value[1].toUpperCase();
return word.substring(0,1);
La declaración de tu método transform, también debería cambiar a: transform (value: Array<string>): string {
Espero te sirva

Comment: listo me sirvio, asi era, muchas gracias compañero

Comment: Excelente, lo voy a agregar como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Está sería la solución para el problema planteado.

```
export class CambiarPipe implements PipeTransform {

// valor de value: ["008", "OPERATING"]
transform (value: Array): string { 

   // value[1] Seleccionas la segunda posición del array "OPERATING"
   const word = value[1].toUpperCase();
   // Retornas la primera letra de la palabra
   return word.substring(0,1);

}
```